# FileReader.readAsDataURL() not working for Video in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, video, filereader

I am writing this piece of code to convert a file (image/video) to base64string and then pass into react components of image and Video.

But this is only working for Image and not for Videos.

```
  captureFile(event){
    const file = event.target.files[0]
    const reader = new window.FileReader()

    reader.onloadend = () => {
      console.log(reader.result)
      this.setState({ image:  reader.result })
      
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(file)
  }
```

Please help.