# Convert a Video Blob URL to Video mp4 File

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webrtc, blob, mediarecorder

I'm trying to convert mediaBlobUrl that I get after recording a video using Media Recorder to a mp4 file,

```
const {
        status,
        startRecording,
        stopRecording,
        mediaBlobUrl,
    } = useReactMediaRecorder({ video: true });

const myFile = new File([mediaBlobUrl], "demo.mp4", { type: 'video/mp4' });
```

But after logging out the file, I always get the file size as 64 Bytes and it doesn't work.

Note: However If I download the file using blob url like this,

```
<a href={mediaBlobUrl} download="myFile">Download file</a>
```

And then upload the file and check its size, it is working fine.

Is there any other way to convert the blob Url to a mp4 video file?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533691/how-to-create-blob-of-a-video-file

Answer (score 4):

The `mediaBlobUrl` provided by react-media-recorder is an object URL and not a  `Blob`. That's why the conversion to a `File` fails.

There is an [`onstop`](https://github.com/0x006F/react-media-recorder#onstop) function which allows you to access the `Blob` directly. But you can also convert the object URL back into a `Blob` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52410044).

```
const mediaBlob = await fetch(mediaBlobUrl)
    .then(response => response.blob());

const myFile = new File(
    [mediaBlob],
    "demo.mp4",
    { type: 'video/mp4' }
);
```

Please note that this will only produce a valid file if the `MediaRecorder` was actually configured to record an mp4.